# What value resistors should I use for this LED?

Tags: led, rgb

I'm trying to figure out the actual value resistance I need for the RGB LED I bought from here: http://www.adafruit.com/products/314#Description

According to most of the online calculators, for the Red LED I need 120R, Green needs 24R, and Blue needs 24R.

Can anyone confirm that these are suitable values to get both bright and even illumination? Also, I calculated these values taking the maximum voltage drop into account, so 2.5 for Red and 4.5 for Green and Blue. Is this the best way of calculating the values?

Comment: What voltage are you running on? sounds like ~5v from the values using but that would be good to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

This is running on the assumption that you are using a supply of 5v.

For the resistor calculations you want to use Ohms law V = IR, where I is the current you want to flow through the LED and V is the voltage difference between what you are supplying and what the LED is specified for. The voltage you want to use is the typical voltage listed on the datasheet, so for the case of red you have (5v - 2.1v) = 20mA * R -> R = 2.9v/20mA = 145 Ohm. The green and blue channels are calculated similarly using a voltage of 3.8v and 2.7v respectively.

Comment: This is correct. If the application is battery powered or in any other way needed to be energy efficient, you can use resistors with a way higher value to reduce the current whilst it still transmits light. I used resistors up to 4K7 with similar LEDs and it's working fine.

Comment: Going higher will never hurt - it will only make the LED dimmer. (Unless you go *too* high -  then you would get *no* LED output.)